# The quotient ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to ask about some help for proving that the quotient ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic ( $Q(\mathbb{C}[z]) \subset  M(\mathbb{C})$, where $M(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of all meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ ).

Good, i know that if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions, then the function $h:=\frac{f}{g}$ is meromorphic with the condition that $g\neq 0$. The polynomials with coefficient in $\mathbb{C}$ are obviously holomorphic.

Do you have any ideas how to move on if the idea is correct at all?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need to move on: what you say suffices!

Answer (score 2):

Terminological remark: I think you meant *quotient field* (also known as the [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions)). [Quotient ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) is what you get by taking the quotient by some ideal in the ring.

And: yes, there is not much to say here: the quotient $f/g$ of two polynomials (with $g$ not identically zero) is  a meromorphic function, because polynomials are holomorphic.